# Is there a way to copy the predicates from one IQueryable to add to a new IQueryable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, predicate, iqueryable

The issue is this. I have 2 tables, both called Document and both have the same columns but are on 2 separate databases. I need to query both in order to grab a document as one table is an extension of the other. Here is an example of the current query being used to grab from the first database:

```
Context.Documents.Where(d => d.Organization_ID == orgId && d.IsActive && d.EntityType == PrimaryType.Employee && d.EntityId == id);
```

I am trying to call a extension method, a regular method would work too though, and pass it this IQueryable and the 2nd database context and do something to this affect where I can copy the predicates over to the new query so they will be the same:

```
public static IQueryable<IDocument> GetDocument<T>(this IQueryable<IDocument> query, DocumentContext docContext)
        {

            var newQuery = docContext.Document.Predicates = query.predicates;
            var joinedQuery= query.Union(newQuery);
                              
            return joinedQuery;
        }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You could store the expression first, then apply it to both calls.  `Expression<Func<IDocument,bool>> predicate = d => ...;` and `.Where(predicate)` in both places.

Comment: You could create an expression and pass that to both, but this will break when your entities properties change (i.e. with two different databases) or when one of the databases has to have another condition applied to its query.

Comment: If possible really need to copy the expression as this is used all over the place and they aren't all the same

Comment: Once you apply `.Where` and get back a new `IQueryable<T>`, the expression is baked in. The internals of LINQ providers are deep and mutable (non-public classes that can change without notice), so while you could use reflection to dig in and find the expression, that success may be short-lived; expect it to be a timebomb. Take another look at what I suggested. You might need to restructure some of your code to accomodate it but it will allow you to reuse your predicates, and the flow of that information will make a lot more sense in the long run.

Comment: Hmmm fair enough then. Could you give me an example using my example above so i have an idea on how to implement it correctly?

Comment: I already gave you the basic concept in my first comment. If you need more than that, you'll need to provide more context.

Comment: What is the problem? You can get query.Expression, copy what you need. Then call `query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(newExpr);`